# Convert a Web site for Mobile devices On Premise

Tags: html, mobile, web

I got a requirement! I would like to convert Normal Web Sites for Mobile Web Sites.
Actually I want a on premise software recommendation that has the capability to do the same as www.dudamobile.com for example.

Kind regards. 
(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score -1):

one of the things you could do is implent the Bootstrap CSS Framework (or any other CSS Framework), to style the website more mobile freindly.

Alot of CSS Frameworks are made to auto-adjust more freindly to native mobile browsers and other mobile browsers, and work for various screen sizes.

see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile

Comment: thanks for the replay.! 
But, what I'm looking for, is an on-premise app with the same capabilities with the [www.dudamobile.com].